# Adding a fourth column for widgets in a footer area

Tags: wordpress, widget, footer

My footer area currently has 3 widgets in 3 colummns. When I add a fourth widget to the area it breaks it up so it becomes 2 lines of widgets, with 2 columns on each line.

I'd like to just make the footer area have 4 columns for widgets, all on one line.

I found this code in the functions.php area and I'm not sure how to adjust the code. Many thanks.

> Register widgetized area and update sidebar with default widgets 
>   The first widget is not needed, but the default widgets are here.. so
>   :(  
>  If I update the options then switching theme will result in a
>   loss of customization. 
>  This solution is not very elegant.

```
function emerald_e_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Footer', 'emerald_e' ),
        'id'            => 'footer',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h3>',
        'after_title'   => '</h3>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'emerald_e_widgets_init' );
```

Comment: You'll need to edit the CSS. The footer widgets are probably too wide thus they break to a new line. What's the URL of the site?

Comment: Thanks bezierer. It's http://emeraldevents.ca.

Answer (score 0):

The following code, when placed in your CSS file should accomplish the 4 column grid you're looking for. Normally  I'd prefer to use % widths but your theme seems to be using px everywhere so I just stuck with that.

```
.fb_iframe_widget span {
    max-width: 210px;
 }

 #tertiary .widget {
    width: 210px;
}
```

Comment: Hi bezierer. Should I be adding that code anywhere in particular within the CSS file? I tried adding it right before the last } in the file but it didn't seem to make a difference. It's still breaking into two lines when I add the fourth widget.

Comment: I also tried added it in the Sidebar section of the CSS code where all the other #tertiary code is but it had the same result.

I also tried changing the width of the FB widget in the widget area of wordpress dashboard but it keeps defaulting back to 292px width.